# Can't open .fsx file in Visual Studio via Windows Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, f#, f#-interactive

On one of my computers, If I double click on a .fsx file in Explorer, or if I right click and do "Open with..." Visual Studio 2012 or 2013, then I get a message box with the error:

"There was a problem whilst sending the command to the program"

Perhaps Visual Studio is trying to execute the script rather than just edit it? Could anyone tell me how to work around this, short of opening up Visual Studio first and then going File->Open?

It works fine on my other computer, so it must be a config issue of some description.

Comment: This looks like it might be a better fit for [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: super user doesn't even have an F# tag, but still, I've now posted the question there as well

Comment: I can not reproduce, it opens fine in VS2013 here. Nonetheless, emacs is the answer.

Comment: I'd rather program in Visual Basic than be forced to use emacs